# chef-solo hangs at the end installing redis

Tags: redis, chef-solo

chef-solo hangs at the end when installing redis as if chef is waiting for some event to occur. Here is output when I had to kill it with ctrl+c.

[2013-05-14T15:55:27+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-05-14T15:55:27+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 8 resources updated 
[2013-05-14T15:55:27+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/ubuntu/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-05-14T15:55:27+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::MultipleFailures: Multiple failures occurred:
* SystemExit occurred in chef run: service[redis] (redis::default line 107) had an error: SystemExit: exit
* Chef::Exceptions::Exec occurred in delayed notification: service[redis] (redis::default line 83) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec: /sbin/start redis returned 1, expected 0

I am new to chef and unable to figure out why this is happening. Has anyone noticed this behaviour before?

Here is my recipe file

```
package "build-essential" do
  action :install
end

user node[:redis][:user] do
  action :create
  system true
  shell "/bin/false"
end

directory node[:redis][:dir] do
  owner node[:redis][:user]
  group node[:redis][:user]
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end

directory node[:redis][:data_dir] do
  owner node[:redis][:user]
  group node[:redis][:user]
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end

directory node[:redis][:log_dir] do
  owner node[:redis][:user]
  group node[:redis][:user]
  mode "0755"
  action :create
end

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/redis-2.6.10.tar.gz" do
  source "http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.10.tar.gz"
  action :create_if_missing
end

# Adding 'make test' causes the install to freeze for some reason.
bash "compile_redis_source" do
  cwd Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
  code <<-EOH
    tar zxf redis-2.6.10.tar.gz
    cd redis-2.6.10
    make && sudo make install
    # to give permissions to the executables that it copied to.
    chown -R redis:redis /usr/local/bin
  EOH
  creates "/usr/local/bin/redis-server"
end

service "redis" do
  provider Chef::Provider::Service::Upstart
  subscribes :restart, resources(:bash => "compile_redis_source")
  supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true
end

template "redis.conf" do
  path "#{node[:redis][:dir]}/redis.conf"
  source "redis.conf.erb"
  owner node[:redis][:user]
  group node[:redis][:user]
  mode "0644"
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "redis")
end

template "redis.upstart.conf" do
  path "/etc/init/redis.conf"
  source "redis.upstart.conf.erb"
  owner node[:redis][:user]
  group node[:redis][:user]
  mode "0644"
  notifies :restart, resources(:service => "redis")
end

service "redis" do
  action [:enable, :start]
end
```

There are 2 service "redis" resource statements, is that a problem? or how does chef workout in this case, does it merge into a single resource when running? 

I am using upstart and here is the redis.upstart.conf.erb file. Not sure if anything is wrong with this. Does the order of the statement matter in this file?

```
#!upstart
description "Redis Server"
emits redis-server

# run when the local FS becomes available
start on local-filesystems
stop on shutdown

setuid redis
setgid redis
expect fork

# Respawn unless redis dies 10 times in 5 seconds
#respawn
#respawn limit 10 5

# start a default instance
instance $NAME
env NAME=redis
#instance $NAME

# run redis as the correct user
#setuid redis
#setgid redis

# run redis with the correct config file for this instance
exec /usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf

respawn
#respawn limit 10 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Dmytro was on the right path, but not exactly.

I see that you are using Upstart as the service provider in Chef. Please check your Upstart config for `redis-server` for any `expect` statement. If you have an `expect fork` or `expect daemon` statement in there, it means that when starting `redis-server`, Upstart will be waiting for the Redis service to fork once or twice respectively. If you have `daemonize no` in the `redis.conf`, Redis process will never fork, and therefore Upstart just hangs at the execution of the init script.

Answer (score 0):

Your redis is not failing to start, it simply runs in the foreground.

I had similar problem with one of the Redis cookbooks I was using. In the `redis.conf.erb` file it had configuration option

```
daemonize no
```

Some other cookbooks have this option configurable by attribute. So, your fix would depend on the cookbook you are using. Either edit your `redis.conf.erb` file or find how that attribute is configured and set it to `yes`.

Comment: redis server itself was started but the chef-solo hanged at the end

Comment: Chef-solo is not hanged, simply redis runs in foreground and not releasing the terminal. Change redis config to say 'daemonize yes' and see if it helps.

Comment: Did that help finding your solution? If so could you please accept my answer. Or give some details how you fixed it? Thanks.

Comment: redis was running in the background but the terminal wasn't released. I had to use Ctrl+C to come out. That 'daemonize yes' was already set in the redis.conf.erb file.

Comment: `daemonize no` is needed so init can manage the process.  If you set `daemonize yes`, although it won't "hang" on start, you cannot `stop` or check the `status` of it using the `service` command or the `/etc/init.d/redis-server` script.